# How do I avoid compatibility warnings with NuGet?

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I'm building a .NET Core 2.0 application for Linux. Here are the relevant parts of the project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I'm having some less-than-awesome behavior from the package system. I am allowed to add [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/). I might not see that it's only compatible with .NET Framework 4.0.

```
PS> dotnet add package System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension
  Writing C:\Users\anthony.mastrean\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4823.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension' into project 'Example.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for Example.csproj...
warn : Package 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension 5.2.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
info : Package 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project 'Example.csproj'.
info : PackageReference for package 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension' version '5.2.3.0' added to file 'Example.csproj'.
```

When I build, it's "successful", but with a warning (snipped for clarity)...

```
PS> dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.5.180.51428 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

...

Build succeeded.

Example.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension 5.2.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
Example.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension 5.2.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
    2 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:09.08
```

A couple of questions...

- Why does dotnet/nuget allow me to add this package to a netcoreapp2.0 project?
- Why or how can I stop this from happening?

I know there is [a perfectly good package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) that's compatible with .NET Core 2.0 that provides the same features. I want this to *fail* and to fail *obviously*! I also know that I can't "upgrade" a nuget warning to an error (too bad).

Answer (score 5):

NuGet treats .NET 4.6.1 assemblies as compatible with .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Standard 2.0 but shows you a warning to indicate that if the NuGet package uses native APIs, such as WPF, then your application may not work.

You could enable warnings as errors which would cause the restore to fail for the NU1701 warnings.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Or just mark the NU1701 warning as an error.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <WarningsAsErrors>$(WarningsAsErrors);NU1701</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Unfortunately this does not prevent `dotnet add package` from failing to add the PackageReference but the restore will fail.